# Focus on a Border in a Canvas

Tags: wpf, canvas, focus, border

I have a Canvas and in it a Border. Now I want to give focus to this Border.
Can somebody please tell me how do do this?

Answer (score 4):

First, make sure you have Border.Focusable = True.  After that, just call Border.Focus() and you should be good to go.

Comment: Not sure why you were downvoted.  This worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score -2):

I haven't tried it for `Border`s, but with a WPF `ContentControl`, I think I had to set `IsTabStop` and `IsEnabled` to `true` to get it to be able to accept focus.

Comment: `IstabStop` is defined in Control, and Border does not derive from Control.